# Mess in php file when edited on different computers?

Tags: php, formatting

I work home with Dreamweaver cs5 on windows 7 and on work on windows xp Dreamweaver cs5.5
When i edit file home and open it from ftp on my work all spaces between lines of code double when i get home and open file there are additional space line added to each empty line why is this happening?

e.g.

```
if (true) {

 test();

};
```

now looks like

```
if (true) {





 test();





};
```

and this is everywhere.
Also sometimes rarely i open file and my php code does not have no new lines its all on the same big line like this.

```
if (true) {     test();  };
```

Someone knows whats the problem here?

Comment: Have you asked DW support about this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: This possibly has to do with the difference in line endings, between `\n` on Linux, and `\r\n` on Windows.  I've never seen that crop up in Dreamweaver though.  Is anything on the server processing these pages?  Is anyone else opening them in a different editor?

Comment: as far as i know some ftp servers try to fix these issues and my mess things up instead of help you. (At least the RFC specifies options for this).

Comment: It might be FTP i use FLASH FXP v4 on work and v3.x on home i think this even happened with notepad++ in the past rarely might be ftp server + or software issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be not best answer, but...
Dreamweaver is wrong tool, use normal IDEs - [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webide) or [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/).

Comment: Sorry but OP is asking about dreamweaver and not about which other IDE to use. You're not really giving an answer here, be fair and questioning the OP's motivation is not qualifying as an answer.

Comment: @hakre feel free to downvote my answer if you think that here is wrong information. Dreamweaver is a crap and this answer can be very useful for OP.

Comment: When i used Frontpage as newbie someone told me its crap i tried dreamweaver and i loved it. I used Notepad++ but dream weaver has better code highlighting and you can manage projects etc.
What makes it "crap" exactly?

Comment: Try normal IDE to see the difference. NetBeans is free. And code highlighting is just nothing in comparison with good autocompletion.

Comment: okay i will try but code highlighting important for me more Dreamweaver gives you auto completion too i like it, there's also nice feature of notepad++ is when you click on open tag e.g. { it will select the closing tag } and you can see if you missed some, wonder if IDE will have same them i might use it

Comment: A great 'bridge' IDE is Coda - it even has a built in SFTP client like Dreamweaver. Johnds, you will notice you work significantly faster with an IDE like Coda, particularly for server-side languages like PHP.

Comment: @g_thom I never saw Coda (I use PC), and I have nothing against it, just to compare: PHPStorm has built in sftp-client to, and with mappings, so after editing script you shouldn't open tree of files, select your script and then copy it to remote dir - just press one button and all will be done automatically.

Comment: @OZ_, thanks for the tip. I'm going to try PHPStorm. One thing I don't like about Coda is that it doesn't have code collapsing by default. Otherwise, I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: @Johnds why are using Notepad++ as an example? It is just a notepad. The OP is referring to a fully fledged development IDE. Notepad++ is not that, and neither is Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the file
2. Click CTRL + F
3. Select "Current document" in "Find in" (You can also select the
   folder if you have multiple files)
4. Search in "Source code"
5. Tick "Use regular expression"
6. Type `"[\r\n]{2,}"` (without quotes) in "Find"
7. Type `"\n"` (without quotes) in "Replace"
8. Press "Replace All"

Comment: This works! however, you did not explain why this works. Can you please , or anyone please explain why this happens???

Answer (score 1):

This is something that does come up with Dreamweaver and it happens when you're on a Windows machine and you download a file from a Unix server.

There's a fairly easy fix to immediately get rid of the *extra line breaks* at least, if that's the current issue, and to prevent them in the future:

http://www.jaredstenquist.com/2009/02/13/removing-extra-linebreaks-and-spaces-in-dreamweaver/

When removing extra line breaks, it will remove all empty breaks so be sure this is what you want - you may have to create some manual breakss over again.

As for line breaks not appearing in rare cases, I suspect setting line break type to match your sever's as suggested in that article may address that issue as well.

Comment: thanks that solved my headache, in certain files space between lines was size of the screen

Comment: @Johnds, glad that helped. If this was useful for you, consider marking this answer as accepted.